# How to get best performance of 8 core system using INTEL fortran

Tags: intel-fortran

Please let me know how to set INTEL fortran compiler option to gain the best performance of 8 core system for IA32 and X64 bits. Actually I want to execute a fortran program and take the advantages of the all CPU time available in 8 core system. Now the program is only using 13 % of CPU time.

Comment: Hmm.  You didn't state much about your problem.  I infer you are hoping to take advantage of parallelism (e.g. multi-threading (over the cores) and vectorization (e.g. SSE SIMD execution) for faster execution.  For some reason you have chosen FORTRAN.  Perhaps you could review this data sheet, http://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/XE/visual_fortran_composer_xe_brief.pdf
and refine your question.  Do you want help generally mapping an algorithm to a parallel implementation?  Do you want help specifically using particular parallelism features of Intel FORTRAN, MKL, IPP, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about autovectorization and guided auto-parallelization features of Intel FORTRAN in this tutorial: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/start/win/tutorial_comp_for_win.pdf.

If you are doing linear algebra, solvers, FFTs, you might get best results if you map your problem into calls into the Intel Math Kernel Libraries: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/
which are already multithreaded and vectorized and cache optimized.

If you are doing media / signal processing you might map your problem into calls into the Intel Performance Primitives library: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

In my specific application, a computational network model containing several loops running thoughout 20k iterations, each iteration accessing a number of nested `if's`, just by enabling /Q2 level optimization in the compiler was sufficient to reduce the computing time drastically, while keeping the CPU load around 15%.
On a similar note, I have noticed rising the optimization setting to the last level (/Q3), did do what you were asking (running all CPUs at about full load), but the computing time have NOT been reduced at all.
Therefore, if one has a small problem and several cases to test and processing capacity is the only bottleneck, it could be a good idea to open more than one Fortran solution and run those cases simultaneously.